# How to delete found values from Vlookup function but not from excel itself, so the vlookup wont search the cells again

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I got 2 columns on 2 sheets of ~100000 cells long.
Those columns look like this:

```
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 3 | c |
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
| 5 | e | 
---------
```

and this:

```
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
| 3 | k |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
```

Now I am comparing the first columns to each other, if they match it has to check if the second column also matches. So the result will look like this:

```
---------------------
| 1 | a | correct   |
---------------------
| 2 | b | correct   |
---------------------
| 3 | c | wrong     |
---------------------
| 4 | d | correct   |
---------------------
| 5 | e | not found |
---------------------
```

I am using this function to do this: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A3;newsheet!A:B;2;FALSE)=B3;"Correct";"Wrong");"Not Found")` But to do this, it takes very long, I am using excel 2016 and all my 4 processors. Now it calculates slower and slower, probably because I got the first column on  alphabetical order both, but the deeper it gets, the more rows it is going to check. So is there any way to let the VLOOKUP function not check the cells, it did already found an agreement.

So in my example: if it found the `| 1 | a |`, the next round it will search only the following remaining items:

```
---------------------
| 2 | b | correct   |
---------------------
| 3 | c | wrong     |
---------------------
| 4 | d | correct   |
---------------------
| 5 | e | not found |
---------------------
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out with this problem

Comment: Are the first column always the same on both sheet?

Comment: the column are always the same @Susilo

Comment: @ThomasInzina Everything you see in my example, is what I use in excel :P

Comment: @ThomasInzina Should I put those 2x2 columns in a list, and then do some coding over it?

Comment: @ThomasInzina I want to filter all the values which doenst match or doenst even exist in a newer version

Comment: just suggestion: the problem you facing can be easily solved using SQL.. but you need at least MS-Access for it.. by least means smallest learning curve..

Comment: @Susilo you can use ADODB with excel to do all the basic C.R.U.D (Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the values to dynamically update; the VBA is a better alternative to 100K formulas.  Using an ArrayList and arrays it took 1.98 seconds to process the data.

```
Sub ValidateData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'You'll need to adjust these const values
    Const LOOKUP_SHEET As String = "newsheet"
    Const TARGET_SHEET As String = "oldsheet"
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim data As Variant, results As Variant
    Dim key As String
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets(LOOKUP_SHEET)
        'Load the values from columns A and B into an array
        data = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
    End With

    For x = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        'Create a unique identifier
        'using a delimiter to ensure value don't mix
        key = data(x, 1) & "|" & data(x, 2)
        If Not list.Contains(key) Then list.Add key
    Next

    With Worksheets(TARGET_SHEET)
        'Load the values from columns A and B into an array
        data = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
        'Resize the results array
        ReDim results(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 1)

        For x = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            'Create a unique identifier
            'using a delimiter to ensure value don't mix
            key = data(x, 1) & "|" & data(x, 2)
            results(x, 1) = IIf(list.Contains(key), "Correct", "Wrong")
        Next

        .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(results, 1)) = results
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't post comments because of rep issues, but assuming they are sorted suitably this *I think* does what you ask.

Edit:

Also if you want to check both columns at once instead of going one at a time, you can join the two columns to make a proxy. i.e. Autofilling down =A1 & B1

So you get a third column containing

1a
2b
2c

etc.

Cuts the vlookups required in half :)

```
Sub ihopethishelps()

Dim last As Long
Dim r As Long


Range("B1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
last = ActiveCell.Row - 1
Range("C1").Select

For r = 0 To last

ActiveCell.Offset(r, 0).Value = _
"=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A" & r + 1 & ",Sheet2!A" & r + 1 & ":O" & last & ",2,FALSE)=B" & r + 1 & "," & Chr(34) & "Correct" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Wrong" & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & "Not Found" & Chr(34) & ")"

Next

End Sub
```